# Declare as parent interface and initialize as child instance

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have always seen collections data structures being instantiated as child instances and declare by their parent interfaces.
Eg.

```
Set<E> collection1 = new HashSet<E>();
Map<E> collection1 = new HashMap<E>();
```

What is the reason behind this. The child classes will inherit all the methods and all the methods that are mentioned in Java documentation from the child classes are overridden but have same meaning. Then what is the reason to declare them are their parent interface.

Any inputs will greatly help me in making my basics stronger.

---

EDIT

Thanks for your feedback. I get the point.
But in changing

```
Set<E> collection1 = new HashSet<E>();
```

to

```
Set<E> collection1 = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
```

we will lose our reference to our original HashSet as we are declaring a new LinkedHashSet for the reference set. So what was the point in doing this?
If there was any way in which we could cast the old implementation to a new one without losing data, then it would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called coding to an interface . This is basically done so that you can change the underlying implementation of the interface later without much change in the code elsewhere. You can substitute any *concrete* implementation later.

```
Set<E> collection1 = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
```

Any method or code expecting the interface type can be provided with any of its implementation type .

As per *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

> If appropriate interface types exist, then parameters, return values, and fields should all be declared using interface types. If you get into the habit of using interface types, your program will be much more flexible. It is entirely appropriate to refer to an object by a class if no appropriate interface exists.

This is what [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says :

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., objects of type S may be substituted for objects of type T) without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task performed, etc.).

Somewhat I believe is that *Your code shouldn't rely on the implementation details of an object, just its published interface.*

Comment: Probably worth noting the underlying implementation is also referred to as the 'concrete implementation' as well.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats the variable as the abstract type (eg `Set`, meaning you can swap in a new concrete implementation later if needed (one of the various Set implementations in the JDK or your own).

This is good programming practice, as it reduces coupling.

It is formally known as the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).